# Send Extra Custom parameters to PayPal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Is it possible to send custom parameter to Paypal ? I am doing it as follow.

```
 <%= form_tag 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', authenticity_token: false do %>
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="foobar@gmail.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="#{dashboard_url}">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="parrtyyyyy">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">

      `######## custom parameters ##########`
      <input type="hidden" name="event_name" value="testing">
      <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="123">

      <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
  <% end %>
```

Form get submitted everything works like a charm but when i logged in to my business account to get the details of event I see nothing, there is no `event_name` or `event_id`.

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `options` variables `on0` through `on9` for the name and `os0` through `os9` for the values, or if using the upload command use `on0_N` and `os0_N` where `N` is the item you are uploading eg: `amount_1` etc.

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0_1" value="event_name">
<input type="hidden" name="os0_1" value="testing">

<input type="hidden" name="on1_1" value="event_id">
<input type="hidden" name="os1_1" value="123">
```

and it will show in the transaction details:

[image: Cart Contents]

Comment: Still unable to view my custom variables :( ... I have done exactly same as you did.

Comment: Ah, hmm I tested using ADD instead of UPLOAD.. Let me try some things.